# How to select block of text in xterm

Tags: gnome-terminal, xterm, terminal-emulator, gnome-terminator

In some terminal emulators like
*gnome-terminal* or *terminator*, I am able to select a block of text by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then clicking the mouse and dragging. This is useful, let's say, to select an indented block of code without all the surroundings, see figure.

[image: Difference between pressing Ctrl while clicking and dragging the mouse]

Is it possible to do something similar in *xterm*?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality in `xterm`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232017/block-selection-in-xterm) is what you are looking for as an alternative. If you do not want to use your mouse, advise [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312213/how-do-i-copy-text-from-my-xterm-without-a-mouse).

Comment: Thanks I've seen those links before I posted my question and was hoping to get luckier that those guys before me. About the alternatives they present, they are not practical for me, too many steps for and operation that shouldn't take more than 3 seconds.